# Can you run and compile Swift code on Windows?

Tags: windows, swift

With the release of Swift 3.0 being available for Mac OS and Windows, does this mean you can compile and run Swift code on Windows? If so what *compiler* do you use for Windows?

Comment: most of the answers to this question are quite old and out of date. I added a community wiki answer with some additional info.

Answer (score 8):

There is an *open source* project on GitHub that (quote) "*provides an easy-to-use development environment for Swift programming for Windows applications*": [**Swift for Windows**](https://swiftforwindows.github.io/).

[image]

### System Requirement

- Windows 10 64bit, Windows 7 64bit

---

#### NOTE

The project was initially hosted on Microsoft [CodePlex](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=swiftforwindows), but then moved to GitHub.

Comment: Swift for Windows is no longer needed for Swift 5.x and above. You can just download Swift itself from swift.org

Answer (score 2):

Since Swift got open sourced, many more platforms were supported by Swift.

Linux was added shortly after it was open sourced, and just recently, the Android support for Swift was merged into the master branch.

You can track the progress of porting Swift to Windows [here](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-34). As you might see, it's not currently being worked on actively by the Swift team, there is, however, a community port on [Github](https://github.com/tinysun212/swift-windows/releases/tag/swift-msvc-20160412) trying to port Swift to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write, build and run Swift code on Windows. With "Siver" and "Elements".

Silver is a free implementation of Apple's Swift programming language. With Silver, you can use Swift to write code directly against the .NET, Java, Android and Cocoa APIs.

Elements is a compiler and development tool chain for Oxygene, C# and Swift which targets the .NET runtime, Java/Android virtual machines. Elements is developed by RemObjects Software (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RemObjects_Software).

HelloWorld.exe example here:
https://github.com/alexbaban/Various-Programming-Languages/blob/master/Swift/Building%20Swift%20Code%20On%20Windows.md

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> With the release of swift 3.0 being avaliable for Mac OS and Windows

But this hasn't been announced officially.

There's some projects, but nothing from Apple... yet.

And anyway, the site [where you read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675079/can-you-run-and-compile-swift-code-on-windows#comment60943692_36675798) this:

> [swift.im/releases.html](https://swift.im/releases.html)

is **not about Apple's Swift**, it's an entirely different project with, unfortunately, the same name.

Comment: The user who downvoted this answer probably didn't understand that OP originally was actually asking about swift.im and not Apple's Swift (see OP's comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675079/can-you-run-and-compile-swift-code-on-windows/36677024#comment60943692_36675798)).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, as of [September 2020](https://www.swift.org/blog/swift-on-windows/) Swift is [available as a binary download](https://www.swift.org/download/) for windows. There are even [windows-specific instructions for getting started](https://www.swift.org/getting-started/#on-windows).
2. The OP asked about which compiler is used. I believe the swift binary is what actually builds the code into an executable. (As of the blog post in 2020, it was `CMake`, but swift packages are now supported, as well as the `swift build` command.)

This question is quite old, so no doubt the other answers were all correct when they were written, but this shows up prominently in search results, and should probably have a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: Swift is available for linux and you can expect swift for Windows, Android soon in the future.

If you want to use Swift language on windows, you must be rely on web based platform. For example: http://swiftstub.com , http://www.runswiftlang.com , etc.

Silver runs on Windows and allows you to compile Swift code to Java and .NET.

Comment: If you go to the swift website it says it is avaliable for windows now.

Comment: @user6075721 what website? where does it say that?

Comment: @user6075721 This is not Apple's Swift. :D